# Any tips on how to get a cheap flight to China

Tags: air-travel, china, flight-search-engines

A month ago, I saw US$500 round trip flights from Dallas to Shanghai. Now I can't seem to get anything less than $750, no matter what time of the year pick. I am searching Expedia, and Travelocity.

I am going to wander around China to immerse myself in the language, for a month, as a continuation of my Mandarin language studies - so I am not fussy about what time I go. I just want to lower my costs.

Do you have any tips for me? How can I get the cheapest flight to China?

Comment: I found some $500 ish deals from DFW to PEK in September on skyscanner.com. Cheapest to PVG at that time was about $650.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you could read Chinese. I would suggest that you look into the Chinese websites of major airlines such as Hainan Airlines, China Eastern etc, or do some digging on the websites of China's domestic third party agencies like Ctrip, Fliggy, Tuniu, Qunar etc.